# success of lseek system call in c

Tags: c, system-calls

A small question  about `lseek` (C system call). I know that upon failure the return value of the function will be negative. Can we know for sure that if the return value is not negative the function actually moved to the desired location?

Comment: *Upon successful completion, lseek() returns the resulting offset location as measured in bytes from the beginning of the file.  Otherwise, a value of -1 is
     returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error.*

Comment: if all else fails read the manual (or man page)

Comment: In general, if a system call has a way to report an error, and it doesn't report the error, then it was successful. If they could fail without reporting it, it would be practically impossible to write reliable code.

Comment: Which OS/compiler are you using. `lseek()` is not in the standard C library.

Comment: @chux I am using the gcc compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is `(off_t)-1`, there was an error.

If the value isn't `(off_t)-1`, the call was successful.

From my system's man page,

> Upon successful completion, `lseek()` returns the resulting offset location as  measured  in bytes  from  the  beginning  of  the file.  On error, the value `(off_t)-1` is returned and `errno` is set to indicate the error.

There are [mentions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) that `off_t` must be a signed type, so it appear safe to check if the result is negative or non-negative.

Comment: thanks. Is it true for other system calls like read and write?